# Stratified ordinary kriging using gstat and stars packages

Tags: r, gstat, stars

The **gstat** package supports stratified ordinary kriging using **sp** objects as shown at https://github.com/r-spatial/gstat/blob/master/demo/examples.R (the code below).
This year (https://r-spatial.github.io/gstat/news/index.html) **gstat** also got support for **sf** and **stars** objects.
While **sf** and **stars** works well for many geostatistical methods, I am unable to make it work for stratified ordinary kriging.

```r
# an example of gstat + sp
library(gstat)
library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y

meuse$part.a = krige(part.a ~ 1, meuse.grid, meuse, nmax = 1)$var1.pred
#> [inverse distance weighted interpolation]
x1 = krige(
        log(zinc) ~ 1,
        meuse[meuse$part.a == 0, ],
        meuse.grid[meuse.grid$part.a == 0, ],
        model = vgm(.548, "Sph", 900, .0654),
        nmin = 20,
        nmax = 40,
        maxdist = 1000
)
#> [using ordinary kriging]
x2 = krige(
        log(zinc) ~ 1,
        meuse[meuse$part.a == 1, ],
        meuse.grid[meuse.grid$part.a == 1, ],
        model = vgm(.716, "Sph", 900),
        nmin = 20,
        nmax = 40,
        maxdist = 1000
)
#> [using ordinary kriging]
x = rbind(as.data.frame(x1), as.data.frame(x2))
gridded(x) = ~x+y
spplot(x["var1.pred"], main = "stratified kriging predictions")
```

[image]

The main problem is how to use only selected values from a **stars** object.

```r
library(stars)
#> Loading required package: abind
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Linking to GEOS 3.7.1, GDAL 2.3.2, PROJ 5.2.0
library(sp)
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
meuse.grid_stars = st_as_stars(meuse.grid)
meuse.grid_stars[meuse.grid_stars$part.a == 1, ]
#> Warning in structure(eval(rlang::expr(x[[i]][!!!args])), levels = attr(x[[i]], : Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
#>   Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.
```

Is it possible to do stratified ordinary kriging using **gstat** and **stars**?

Comment: I don't know if it may help, but [here](http://132.72.155.230:3838/r/spatial-interpolation-of-point-data.html) a useful (and pretty recent approach) usign sf and stars. Did you find a way to solve that error?

Answer (score 0):

I found similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64541951).
And [the answer was published in github](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/geocompr/issues/585).